# Jfrog artifactory cant'log out in my computer,but log out success in other's computer

Tags: artifactory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy266.png)

The first time i haved installed the jfrog artifactory-oss,i use admin to log in is success,then i log out failed,and my session was transformed to *system*.as you can see,i have never log out success until now,but the other's computer can do this!The artifactory-oss doesn't exists the user of *system*,why do my server is exists，is i am argly?

Comment: I see you are using 6.x Artifactory version and this issue can happen due to browser cache as well. Have you tested by deleting the caches and cookies from the browser?

Comment: Agreed with the above. You can also try in incognito mode

Comment: Thanks for your help,the issue is solved